# laravel dusk invalid session id by testing

Tags: laravel, testing, terminal, invalidoperationexception, laravel-dusk

2. Tests\Browser\MedewerkerContactTest::testGeenBericht
   Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidSessionIdException: invalid session id

the testfile wil return this error message on a random testcase underneath here you can see the complete error message

```
2) Tests\\Browser\\MedewerkerContactTest::testGeenBericht
   Facebook\\WebDriver\\Exception\\InvalidSessionIdException: invalid session id

/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:107
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:372
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:585
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteExecuteMethod.php:27
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/WebDriverOptions.php:166
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:408
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:164
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:242
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:165
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:81
/var/www/tests/Browser/MedewerkerContactTest.php:65

Caused by
Facebook\\WebDriver\\Exception\\InvalidSessionIdException: invalid session id

/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:107
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:372
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:585
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteExecuteMethod.php:27
/var/www/vendor/php-webdriver/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteTargetLocator.php:35
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:295
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:144
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php:242
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:150
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:71
/var/www/tests/Browser/MedewerkerContactTest.php:65
```

please help me
i use laravel version 8 and have the latest chrome driver and use php 7
i tried many things because at first i thought something was wrong with the pc specs and failed because of the insuficiënt ram and i put on many places a wait function.

when it works the most likely failure after is that it cant login i watch the failure png and it seems there it forgot to delete coockies so there may be the error also
the login is a custom function as you can see down below

```
public function login(Browser $browser, string $role = 'klant_beheerder'): Browser
    {
        $browser->visit($this->url . '/')
            ->assertSee('Inloggen')
            ->type('#email', config('dusk.' . $role . '.login'))
            ->type('#password', config('dusk.' . $role . '.password'))
            ->press('.thm-tran-bg');

            return $browser;
    }
```

the wierd part is that other tests do work like this one here below in another file

```
public function testProfiel(): void
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $this->login($browser)
            ->visit($this->url . '/home')
            ->assertSee('e2ebeheerder')
            ->click('#page-header-user-dropdown')
            ->clickLink('Profiel')
            ->assertSee('Profiel van e2ebeheerder')
            ->assertSee('Opslaan')
            ->screenshot('InloggenTest::testProfiel');
    });
}
```

i have tried many things to fix this problem most of them were about flsuhing the session and deleting coockies between tests

Comment: Assuming your test extends `DuskTestCase`. You could make a `public function tearDown()` and put `session()->flush();` and `parent::tearDown();`. This runs after each test. If you would like to continue in Dutch we can start a chat.

Comment: @geertjanknapen i am very new to this platform so i don't know how to start a chat but i'm dutch too. the solution you gave me was great advice but to my regret it didn't solve the problem i still get the same error message. the stupid part is that other files with the same kind of code do work and don't show any sign's of this problem

Comment: Oh wait, you have too little rep to be able to chat, I wasn't aware since I rarely use the chat rooms. Did the `tearDown` method result in any other feedback i.e. new errors, different errors, etc?  Also, you are logging in, right? So you should be able to call a `->logout()` as well then?

Comment: @geertjanknapen i had 1 new error message and that was couldn't find session and after that it goes back to invalid session id i got one other error message i forgot to tell that was 
1) Tests\Browser\ContactTest::tearDownDuskClass
Exception in Tests\Browser\ContactTest::tearDownDuskClass
Curl error thrown for http DELETE to /session/3280de42d689075846e91a800a3c01ef

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused'
and thank you for helping me

Comment: More people seem to have your problem, but it does not necessarily have to do with Dusk. What machine are you running things on? Linux, Windows, Mac, perhaps a Docker environment (I know I am)? [Closed issue on Github of your exact problem.](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/634) and here's something that might fix it, paste it in a `tearDown` method I think in `DuskTestCase`; https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/634#issuecomment-619065659

Comment: Right I did some more digging. Is `deleteAllCookies()` a custom function? If so, could you elaborate on it (update the question with the code)? Other thing I'm wondering, you are logging in as a user stored in database right, so you could use [dusk/src/Concerns/InteractsWithAuthentication.php](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/7.x/src/Concerns/InteractsWithAuthentication.php) in order to `login`, `loginAs` and `logout`. Check out this guide to get an idea of what I mean [guide here](https://5balloons.info/working-with-authentication-in-laravel-dusk/)

Comment: @geertjanknapen deleteAllCookies is not a custom function and i am running in an docker envirement. I found out that the problem only occors when i visit the the contact page the other pages are working fine when i test them using simelair dusk code. the wierd part is that on 25% of the times i test the contact page the first 4 testscases wil be tested and than immeadeatly fails evrything after that and the other 75% it wil just say invalid id by all of them.

Comment: i did also some more testing with flush i got this messege 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [session] does not exist.'

Comment: You should consider using the built-in `login`, `logout` funtionality. Other than that, it is normal that if the test fails, all the tests will fail. The same `Browser` instance keeps running, but the session got 'deleted' which makes it invalid for every single test.

Comment: @geertjanknapen the problem doesn't lay in the login/logout function the problem only occors on the contact page

Comment: Start of by showing all contact test cases.

Comment: @geertjanknapen  thank you for helping me in time of needs i just ran my first test with no errors only failures the problem mostly laid by the method `assertSeeIn` that couldn't find the element because it was inside an iframe(i already fixed that problem) but my tests are still incosistent sometimes it does them al sometimes it just throws away the session at a random point no consistancy at al also the function after the obne with iframe check always doesn't delete coockies

Comment: I'm no Dusk expert. I wrote a whole bunch of tests for our company. They always seemed flaky, I got around this using `->pause()` a lot, other than that I don't really have any other pointers I can give you for now, helaas!

Comment: @geertjanknapen thank you for all your help but i found the answer if you could please upvote something it would really help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved all invalid id by using `--disable-dev-shm-usage` at chromeOptions

in Chrome, I did not have enough resources allocated to my Docker Container. Adding the "--disable-dev-shm-usage" flag to Chrome fixed the issue. Since its using local /tmp instead of it's /dev/shm it has plenty of room.