Laravel dusk can't disable headless mode on laravel sail with wsl2
i have a existing up to date laravel 11 project that's running under laravel sail with docker in windows 11 with wsl2 (ubuntu). i've installed and configured laravel dusk according to the official laravel docs the dusk test are running fine but i cant disable headless mode to open a browser window no matter what i try
The first think i tried was to add DUSK_HEADLESS_DISABLED=true in my .env.dusk.local did not work.
Next i commented out '--headless=new' in the driver method in DuskTestCase.php and did nothing
The same with '--disable-gpu'
Tried adding '--no-sandbox' suggested by chat GPT and guess what? it did nothing
Next i fended a discussion on laracast where someone suggested to change my selenium image in my docker-compose.yml to:
image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome:4.1.2-20220217'

that did not work either.
tried sail down sail up --build -d.
I'm stuck and any help with be greatly appreciated.

a relatable issue like this one is old issue laravel 5.5 this is ofcourse probably outdated i am not sure but it might get you looking in the right direction i myself wil also look for an answer

I know about that post but it-not relevant to my particular situation

this might be stipud to even ask but if i heard your question right you commented out --headless=new and the --disable-gpu at the same time while also having the selenium standalone chrome image
`

another thing you need to do is unlock port 7900 by adding - '${FORWARD_SELENIUM_HEADFUL_PORT:-7900}:7900' to your docker-compose.yml this is found at laracasts also visit then localhost:7900 the credential is 'secret' also add DUSK_HEADLESS_DISABLED=true to your .env

was this what you were looking for because then i will make an official answer for it so the question is resolved and can be easily found for other people

yes, thank  you very much

Run laravel-dusk headless false
Before you can run your laravel dusk tests in a visable browser on laravel sail with wsl2 there are a few steps you need to do beforehand:
Step 1:
You need to edit your DuskTestCase.php like:
 protected function driver()
{
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
        // '--disable-gpu', //disable or remove disable-gpu to run with an browser it needs gpu 
        // '--headless', //disable or remove headless to run with an browser
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage' //this isnt necesery but can help you with future problems look "https://stackoverflow.com/a/75719112/20538588"
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
    );
}

Step 2:
Make sure you also unlock port 7900 and have a chrome standalone image defined. You can do this by configuring you docker-compose.yml like:
selenium:
image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome:4.1.2-20220217' // <---have a chrome image configured
environment:
    LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
volumes:
    - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
ports:
    - '${FORWARD_SELENIUM_PORT:-4444}:4444'
    - '${FORWARD_SELENIUM_HEADFUL_PORT:-7900}:7900' // <---open port :7900
networks:
    - sail

You can then visit the url localhost:7900 the default credential is 'secret'
Step 3:
The last step is configuring you .env by adding: DUSK_HEADLESS_DISABLED=true

that works, thank you very much
